# Responsive menu extending beyond page height

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, responsive-design

I have a responsive menu that extends beyond the page height, which means users cant see the lower menu items on short pages (pages with little content)

`jsfiddle -`http://jsfiddle.net/ashconnolly/QDznX/

I understand that it is because my nav is positioned absolute, however if I set the nav to position relative, it pushes the page content below it down.

How could I manage my html + css better to fix this?

OR

In javascript how do I set the body height to be the same as the menu, when the body height is less than the menu height?

Hope you can help!

Comment: Any chance of a link to the site? The fiddle doesn't help too much, since it's not relative to your exact circumstances occurring on the website. There will be a very simple answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by CSS

Just add couple of css properties for overflow and height for nav.active

```
 nav.active {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
     height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Here is a

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDznX/5/)

Comment: Ah I've just noticed that once you hide the menu after it is shown the scroll bar remains, allowing users to scroll into empty white space.
Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks again!

Comment: ya..hmm.did you fix it?

Comment: Nah I cant work it out, you think it would be a simple case of assigning the previous css styling to the menu when it doesnt have the class active. But I cant seem to get it working :/

Comment: ya i think so.i will see if i can fix it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QDznX/7/ here is an updated fiddle added few lines of css at the end and also slight change to your JS add animation accordingly